# xpath simple understanding example

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I have got this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="positions-zaehlweise.css"?>
<ul>
<li>A</li> 
<li>             
 <ol>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
 </ol>
</li>
<li>D</li>
</ul>
```

and this xpath query:

```
/child::ul/descendant-or-self::*/child::li[position()=1]
```

I am getting from this query: `A` and `B`.

but i somehow dont understand how it does this. With `/descendant-or-self` it is taking as `self` the `A`, right? then it goes down the list and takes all. then how does it compare, my vision is this:

```
self             descendant
----------------------------
A,D                 B, C
```

am i right? can someone please explain me in short how this worked? thanks in tons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/child::ul` returns the `ul`.

`descendant-or-self::*` returns self (`ul` again) plus all its descendants (`li-A`, `li-ol`, `ol`, `li-B`, `li-C`, `li-D`).

`child::li` moves to children of the previous elements that are `li`, which means `li-A`, `li-ol` and `li-D` for `ul`, `and`li-B`and`li-C`for`ol`.

`[position()=1]` only selects those that are the first such child, i.e. `li-A` and `li-B`.